# Authentication in .NET Core Web API not activating

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Am trying to activate JWT token authentication scheme in .net core web api. Its not activating at all.

I configured Swagger to take in a token and give the consumer of the API access to all its controllers. But it just lets everyone get access rather than checking if a valid token exists.

I've tried putting the [Authorize] keyword on all the controllers but it still doesnt work.

Here i provide my startup.cs file

```
namespace Web.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();

            // CORS Configurations
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });

            // Authentication Configurations
            services.Configure<TokenManagement>(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt"));
            var token = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").Get<TokenManagement>();
            var secret = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token.Key);

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = token.Issuer,
                    ValidAudience = token.Audience,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret)
                };
            });

            services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

            services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

            services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(implementationFactory =>
            {
                var actionContext = implementationFactory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
                return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
            });

            services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o => o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV");
            services.AddMvcCore()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddFormatterMappings()
                .AddJsonFormatters();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSwaggerDocumentation(provider);

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute("Printers Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{vendorDriver}/{vendormodel}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`services.AddMvc()` will load the Authorization service(AddAuthorization()) :

```
return services
    .AddMvcCore()
    .AddApiExplorer()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddCors()
    .AddDataAnnotations()
    .AddFormatterMappings();
```

so you can use `services.AddMvc()` or `services.AddMvcCore().AddAuthorization()`

Answer (score 1):

The differences between `services.AddMvc()` and `services.AddMvcCore()` is the services that are loaded inside you application.

`AddMvcCore()` add only the mandatory services to run the Asp.net app, while `AddMvc()` load common used services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna show you the way I made it work in my project (I'm using **ASP.NET Core 2.2**)

```cs
// Inside ConfigureServices

services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie().AddJwtBearer(cfg => {
     cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
    };
});

// Inside Configure
    app.UseAuthentication();

// In the controllers that need Authentication
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class SampleController : ControllerBase {

    }
```

Comment: I really dont know what am doing wrong. I cant get it fired up even with the settings you sent me. Tried to describe the AuthenticationScheme globally in the AddAuthentication() section like AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) so that it applies all over all the controllers but none of that saved me yet

Comment: This approach worked like charm for me in three different projects, have you tried to use them in a brand new project just to check?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i just added the line

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

I dont know why the line

services.AddMvcCore().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2) won't
 activate it